# Statistics of Intervals

Tags: probability, density-function

## Question

Dear all,
Assume you ask N persons to set their personal interval of acceptance (e.g. interval ranging from 0 to 100% for the power of a speaker system) which they would rate as enjoyable. You would end up with a list of intervals. How would you perform proper statistics on that? The point here is that not only the mean of the interval is a relevant value, but also the range as we assume that persons X enjoys every value of its interval the same. Assume we would like to find the power of the speaker which is most pleasant for the total range of asked people. What would you do?

## My Answer so far

What I did so far is summing up all of the intervals to find a cumulative statistical curve and divide this by the number of asked persons N. Hence, I have a curve telling me for every percentage the ratio of acceptance. I could now search for the maximum of this curve to find the most accepted value with the ratio r but this would also mean that 1-r people don't like this value. Other than that I could calculate the mean of the curve according to $\int_0^{100} P(X=x) \cdot x dx$, where x are the percentages and $P(X=x)$ is the probability of this value.

I would highly appreciate every kind of hint or help towards which kind of statistics I'd have to have a look at.

Cheers, Franz.

Comment: You might be overthinking this. From the raw data, just find the value(s) of power that the most people like, aka the mode of the distribution (distribution = number of people who will accept a given value of power distribution). Is there a reason this can't be done in your case?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem here is that the resulting distribution can have two very high values, so kind of two maxima of the level of acceptance. If we assume the case where there are two equally high maxima - which one should I choose? And if I decide for one, is it a fair choice regarding the people whose intervals have been located around the second maximum. My problem with the mode was that then n of N people will be pleased with this value but also N-n not. For this reason I thought of taking the mean.

Comment: OK, are we assuming that people's dislike of a level if proportional to how far it is from their range? eg, a person whose range is 50-75 dislikes 48 twice as much as he dislikes 49? If so, that would be the metric to minimize.

Comment: That's a pretty good idea to search for a metric in this space and then minimize it on the given set-up. I think that your example of the metric should reflect the peoples opinions best. But this is a question of interpretation.
I was just wondering if there exists a more extended theory on this kind of problems. If we break it down it's nothing else than interviewing a group of people and allowing multiple answers. I can't imagine that I should be the first one who thinks about the evaluation of such data.